# How can I remove a specific CSS style using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am absolutly new in **JavaScript** and I have the following problem.

I have a script that is automatically performed when the user click on a button.

I need that this script do also the following operations:

1. **Select an element into my DOM that have a specific ID**
2. This element have setted an inline CSS: `style="display: block;"`, which have to be removed.

How can I do it?

Comment: in jQuery: _$("#id").hide()_

Comment: You should use addClass and removeClass in jQuery if you want your CSS to control the show/hide

Comment: use $('#element').css('display', 'inline').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#id_of_the_element").hide();
```

or

```
$('#id_of_the_element').css('display', '');
```

Comment: mmm what do the hide method? Hide an element? I don't need to hide the element, I simply have to remove the CSS settings because it is the cause of an anomaly

Answer (score 1):

To remove any property, use :

```
  $("#id").css("the_css_property","");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vanilla javascript (that is without any library), do the following:

```
var element = document.getElementById( YOUR_ELEMENT_ID )
element.style.display = ''
```

You effectively just enter the attribute you want and set it to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$("#id").removeAttr("style");
```

> [Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/er4qxezq/)

Comment: removeAttr only work with html attributes, not with CSS attributes. In your example "style" is an inline html attribute, but maybe he wants to delete a css property from a .css file. For that purpose, that doesn't work.

Comment: That is indeed what I understand of the OP's needs, removing html attribute `style`

Comment: but $.removeAttr only works in that situation. This time it works, but maybe not in every situation.

Comment: Are we talking about another situation that the one established in the question ?

Comment: Of course not. Your solution is completely valid for this situation. Just saying that is not a solution for every situation, which I think it would be a better solution. Anyway, yours is valid.

Comment: You're right. If only one inline css attribute must be deleted but not all, I agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

With just JavaScript

```
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("your_elem_id");
    elem.style.display = '';    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can use `$("#ElementID").css("display", "");` to clear the `display` attribute.

If it needs to be something else, just change the second parameter in the `css()` function.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/css/